# Permutations of a binary strings with even number of 1's

Tags: permutations

So I'm a bit rusty, but given a binary string, I'd like to calculate the permutations that exist which contain an even number of 1's within the range of binary 0 to said binary string.

In other words, for all binary strings for the decimal range 0 - n, as n is the given upper bound. Below, I'll use 20 as an example.

For e.g

10100 (dec: 20), and starting from 0:

11 (dec: 3), 1010 (dec: 10) etc.

I figured the calculation would be:

nCr(5,2) + nCr(5,4) as the length is 5, and evens in that range are 2,4. 
This yields 15, though the answer should be 10 (I'm pretty sure)

What am I missing?

Comment: This is not clear.  What does "within the range of binary 0 to said binary string." mean?  What's $n$?  What's $r$?  Can you work an explicit example to show what you mean?

Comment: I apologize! I will try and make the above comment more clear. Essentially, from the range of 0 to 20 (or 0 to 10100 in binary terms).

Answer (score 1):

What goes wrong with your method is that $5 \choose 2$ picks out all strings of length $5$ that have two $1$'s ... but that includes a string like $11000$ which is greater than $20$. Same for $5 \choose 4$: a string like $11011$ should not be included.

Comment: Good note, thank you! So, would it be like; 

nCr(3,1) [ for 1 0 _ _ _ and the 3 remaining to be 1, equaling 2 1's] +
nCr(4,2) [ for 0 _ _ _ _ for the binary range of length 4 & 2 1's] +
nCr(4,4) [ for 1111]

or something close to this..?

Comment: @JackRohme Yes, that works for your specific example .. (and note that 3C1=3, 4C2 = 6, and 4C4=1, so you get 1+6+3=10 ... which I verified is indeed the correct answer).  The question is how to generalize this for any number though ...